# The ear of my 3D head is too pixelated

Tags: 3d-view

I'm a beginner in 3D software and I'm currently trying to create a 3D head.

But I have a problem with the ear: it is too pixelated compared to the rest of the head.

I already tried to separate the ear from the face using *Edit Mode*, but when I pressed <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>, the ear just disappeared. After that I tried using *Subdivision Surface*, but it looked weird.

[image: Here is the face]

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Edit: Here is the download link for the file:

[image]

PS: Yes, I am using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> after <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>.

Comment: Hi. Please don't add "*Solved*" to your question or title. Instead [upvote the post that helped you](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote). If you feel it completely solved your issue consider [marking it as accepted](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer).

Answer (score 2):

Just go into sculpt mode and enable dyntopo:[image]

The lower you set your detail size value the higher resolution you will get. That will automatically add more resolution/geometry to your ear when you sculpt on it.

Comment: In the file the ear has the same density as the mesh because of the remesh. But it looks squarish because the model is flat-shaded (and it has not enough geometry for the details). To use smooth-shaded, switch to *Object* mode, select the model, and use the context menu > *Shade Smooth*.

Comment: Oh thank you its working !

Comment: If you consider that the answer solved your problem, could you consider accepting it by pressing the check icon? (Because that's the rule @Zarckyx ;)

Comment: @Zarckyx This site is not a regular forum, please don't reply "Thanks" as an answer or comment, instead [upvote the post that helped you](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote). If you feel it completely solved your issue consider [marking it as accepted](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer).